# VS2010: New and improved Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

In VB.NET type this on a new line:

```
DateAdd(
```

Shouldn't a dropdown picklist of enum values appear?

It used to! I miss it!

Of course, this is just one example where an enum pick list does not appear where it did before.

Can anyone defend this or is it a bug?

Comment: I tried this repro on my Visual Studio 2010 install and the enum drop down list popped up as expected. One possibility on your machine is that it's prefering the `string` overload of the method as opposed to the enum version. Can you confirm by telling us which tooltip is showing up when you type the ( ?

Comment: Try clicking Ctrl+Space after the opening parenthesis and see if that makes the enum options come up

Comment: Nope...http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/dee5656a-41a7-4f9f-a4cc-b7a3bae409bf/2010-06-07_1903.png

Comment: Judging by that screenshot, you want to click the "Common" tab at the bottom of the intellisense, don't you?

Comment: I have this problem too btw.  No idea why.  Did you try Tools + Import/Export + Reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that all of your Intellisense options are turned on.  I've installed 2010 a few times over the past few months, and the option is turned off by default seemingly at random.  It drives me just a little bit crazy.

Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->General

Ensure "Auto List Members" and "Parameter information" are checked.

If you only want this on for VB you could go into "Basic" instead of "All Languages".

Comment: Nope...
http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/6b4b2760-60ff-4039-9d37-a1fdbd648fb0/2010-06-07_1905.png

Comment: Drat.  It was worth a try.  I've been caught by it enough times to have it seared into my skull.

Comment: I think you got it after all. I think it was related to these settings. I tried unchecking the "Hide Advance members" option for "All Languages," but when I came back in and checked, the option was greyed (mixed setting.) So...I went to the Basic language settings and ensure that it was unchecked. Maybe doing that or resaving the options and re-entering/exiting the option screen made the options stick, I dunno, but it is working now and I think that all this clicking of the options likely fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Damn. It's broken again. I have no idea why. It just seems flakey.